# "Use of undeclared identifier 'debugger' error in React Native project with native modules"

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on a React Native project and have encountered an issue when trying to use a native module. In my C++ code, I'm getting the error Use of undeclared identifier 'debugger'. This error pops up when I try to compile my project.

Here's the snippet of the code where the error occurs:

```
class SharedRuntimeAdapter : public RuntimeAdapter {
public:
    SharedRuntimeAdapter(
        std::shared_ptr<jsi::Runtime> runtime,
        debugger::Debugger &debugger);
    ...
};
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'debugger'
```

I'm working with React Native version 0.70.2, and I'm trying to integrate a native module for debugging purposes. I've checked that my spelling is correct and have attempted to include all relevant headers.

I've tried looking into whether I need to link a library or include a specific header file, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Does anyone know how I can fix this error or what might be causing it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why is this tagged with swift and not c++?